# Swagger, Multiple custom attributes of the same type found

Tags: c#, атрибуты, swagger

В модели я использую атрибуты. 
Для одного и того же свойства использую RequiredAttribute и унаследованный от него кастомный атрибут.
Swagger ругается на такое - Multiple custom attributes of the same type found.

Этот класс использую в качестве модели входных аргуметов для метода POST с указанием [FromBody]. 
Если убираю [FromBody] или один из RequiredAttribute - все ок.

Может кто-то чем поможет?

Comment: Приведите пример кода, пожалуйста. Swagger может ругаться на 2 почти одинаковых POST-endpoint'a

Comment: `Для одного и того же свойства использую RequiredAttribute и унаследованный от него кастомный атрибут`. Подозреваю, что проблема в этом. Скорре всего Swagger либа(кстати не плохо указать какая) не ищет строго RequiredAttribute , а ищет RequiredAttribute и всех унаследованые атрибутов.

Comment: использую Swashbuckle.AspNetCore v3.0.0
endpoint оставил только один на весь проект, специально чтобы отсечь лишнее.